# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority на Golang

Tags: javascript, golang

Имеется *js* код такого типа, который делает запрос к апи и получает от него ответ.

```js
var request = require('request');

var requestOptions = {

    login: {
        url: `${serverUrl}/auth/login`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            emailid: "aaaa@aaa.aaa",
            password: "1234",
            entityType: "user"
        }
    },
};


//send request to server 
function sendRequest({ type, token }) {

    if (requestOptions[type]) {
        requestOptions[type].rejectUnauthorized = false;
        requestOptions[type].json = true;
        if (type === 'login') {
            requestOptions[type].headers = {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(requestOptions[type], (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log({
                        error: "Ok",
                        errMessage: error
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log({ sucess: "Ok", body: response.body });
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid request');
    }
}

sendRequest({ type: 'login' });
```

Пытался его реализовать на *golang* таким образом

```js
type Payload struct {
    Emailid    string  `json:"emailid"`
    Password   string  `json:"password"`
    EntityType string  `json:"entityType"`
}

func Init(apiKey string, apiSecret string) error {
    data := new(Payload)
    data.Emailid = apiKey
    data.Password = apiSecret
    data.EntityType = "user"

    fmt.Println(data)

    payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in Init with payloadBytes, err := json.Marshal(data) %s", err.Error())
    }
    body := bytes.NewReader(payloadBytes)


    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://url/auth/login", body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in Init NewRequest %s", err.Error())
    }
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in Init with resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req) %s", err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    htmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error in Init with htmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) %s", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(htmlData))

    return nil
}
```

Но почему-то запрос к апи возвращает пустой ответ, если запускать код на golang.

Помогите найти ошибку. Заранее буду благодарен.

Comment: А вы пробовали в запросе `Content-Type` проставить?  Некоторые сервера к этому чувствительны.

Comment: Попробовал добавить _req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")_ но это не помогло. 

А не может быть проблемы в том, что в коде на js есть это: 
_requestOptions[type].rejectUnauthorized = false;_
_requestOptions[type].json = true;_

Comment: Про тип это видимо `Content-Type`.  А `rejectUnauthorized` это видимо про плохо настроенный _HTTPS._  Но про это должна была вернуться ошибка.

Comment: На самом деле очень странно, что код на go вообще ничего не возвращает, но при этом код на js выдает правильный ответ.

Comment: Вы, кстати, статусный код проверили?  Может вам сервер 403 без тела отдал.

Comment: А Вы не могли бы подсказать как проверять статусный код?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Status

Comment: Вот что мне возвращает функция _func Post(url, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *Response, err error)_: **x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

Answer (score 6):

Если вы запускаете golang код в docker, возможно поможет вот этот хак в `Dockerfile` если он не [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) добавить такое

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

Если же у вас [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) то там где используется scratch добавить еще такое

```
COPY --from=go-builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Вот [тут](https://preslav.me/2019/08/11/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-running-a-go-app-inside-a-docker-container/) чуть подробней есть инфа.

Answer (score 2):

У вашего сервера плохой сертификат.  Вашим первым инстинктом должно быть
*починить ситуацию с сертификатом на стороне сервера!*

Только когда вы абсолютно уверены, что это невозможно, и только когда вы
готовы нести за это полную ответственность, вы можете отключить проверку
верности сертификата у *HTTP*-клиента:

```golang
// TODO(philipp): UNSAFE! FIX THIS! DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION!
//
// Largely copied from
// https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DefaultTransport.
var client = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: true,
        }).DialContext,
        ForceAttemptHTTP2:     true,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            // See comment above.
            // UNSAFE!
            // DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION!
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
}
```

**Вся ответственность за подобный код лежит на вас!**

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема не в моем коде, а в самом сервере, с api которым я работаю? И как понимать слова про "отвественность"?

Comment: Либо в сервере, либо в сертификатах на вашей машине.  Но как правило это первое.  Про ответственность:  Вы по сути отключаете проверку подлинности сертификата.  Если вместо вашего сервера подставить какой-нибудь ворователь паролей, вы об этом не узнаете.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. Спасибо за ответ.